# Textbox black only in run-time mode

Tags: windows, forms, textbox, runtime

i've a problem with a textbox contained in a groupbox, contained in a panel. When i run program (Windows form, c#, framework 3.5) in debug mode or in my pc it works ok, instead in many other pc i see the textbox all black (it has white backcolor), but i can select the text of it. I don't understand what can be the problem, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you will get any helpful answers with the information you've provided. When you run into a problem, you must start by investigating and problem solving. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have designed the application in VB6, at design time, you get to choose the backcolor and forecolor of the textbox, and that can be accomplished by changing the properties of the textbox.

While changing the color, the system will display two tabs [System] and [Pallete]. if you choose the colors of your text box from the [System] tab, then the color of the textbox will change depending on the different settings of Theme that the user is configuring. Always make sure to choose the colors from the [Palette] tab to ensure consistency at all times, regardless of the theme that the user has configured.